# Cannot load jQuery CDN on chrome - Getting "Your connection is not private" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

**Problem:**

Chrome is not allowing any page(example jsfiddle)  to load : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js , it also doesnt load if i directly paste in address bar. I get the error below.

[image]

**I have tried:**

- Changing it to HTTP, this does work, but i need to use HTTPS (for
  various reasons)  so this is not an acceptable solution.
- Tried   updating the CLRSet in chrome per an SO answer - didnt work
- Removed
  all firewall/antivirus settings
- Rebooted machine
- Re-installed chrome

**Notes:**

It works with no problem on IE/FF etc and also in other peoples' computers

I realize this is a subjective question, but please let me know if there's anything I can do!

**SOLUTION:**

Finally this is what worked for me, thanks to @SaurabhSharma for pointing me to the [post which had the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust/41937#41937) (though it is not the accepted solution)

[image]

Comment: Check in the properties of the certificate. Have a look if its still valid.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Or within a proxy secured network?

Comment: Looking in dev tools, it shows ERR_CERT_REVOKED.  Not good.

Comment: I'm hitting that URL and getting a cert that's good until 1 August 2017 - perhaps you're hitting a cached certificate or a bad node.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni the cert is valid till Aug 2017

Comment: @SaurabhSharma firewall -yes, but i have disabled it now and yet gives the error

Comment: @Dymos how to clear cert cache? I have cleared normal cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Google hosted CDN for libraries instead

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

**Update:**
Certificate errors on chrome occur either because of following:

(1) The System Time is not the real-time.

(2) The SSL certificate has Expired.

(3) Google Chrome is not updated.

(4) The SSL certificate is not Installed properly.

(5) The SSL certificate is not issued by a Trusted Certificate Authority (CA) or a self-signed certificate is used to secure a website.

(6) The website is secured with an outdated 128-bit SSL.

(7) The website is secured with an outdated SHA-1 Algorithm.

**Also check this [solution](https://superuser.com/a/41937/293416)**

Comment: Yes I have done this on new pages, but we have a whole mass of legacy pages using the old references. Also I am unable to open websites like jsfiddle because it internally uses code.jquery.com

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Are you behind a college/organisation firewall? or on a proxy network?

Comment: firewall -yes, but i have disabled it now and yet gives the error

Comment: I didn't meant your device's firewall but a firewall installed on your network.

Comment: oh ok, I will check with my network admin, but not sure if that's the cause because:

1. It works in IE for me
2. It works in Chrome for others in my dev team

Comment: "Also check this solution" this is what finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Until they get their certificate worked out, you could consider using CDNJS instead.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: Yes I have done this on new pages, but we have a whole mass of legacy pages using the old references. Also I am unable to open websites like jsfiddle because it internally uses code.jquery.com